# Mutate a column selected by a string converted to symbol

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to make lower case a column of my dataset

I wrote a basic stupid function

```
    library(dplyr)

    cleaning_tags<-function(data,col) 
    {
      data<-data%>%mutate(!!sym(col)=tolower(!!sym(col))) 
      return (data)

    }
```

where data is a data.frame and column is column name as a string

I don't know the error I'm getting

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "data%>%dplyr::mutate(!!sym("GROUPDSC") ="
```

The `sym` operator seems to work correctly because if I'm trying to do

```
data%>%select(!!sym(col))
```

it select the desired column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `:=` when assigning values to column

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

cleaning_tags<-function(data,col)  {
    data %>% mutate(!!sym(col) := tolower(!!sym(col)))
}

df <- data.frame(a = c("ABC", "DEF"))
cleaning_tags(df, "a")

#    a
#1 abc
#2 def
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different strange things in your code. The function does not return anything (you forgot to return `data`), you can't assign the new column name like this and the code is hard to read.

```
library(tidyverse)

cleaning_tags<-function(data, col) {
  data %>% 
    mutate_at(col, toupper)
}

ir <- cleaning_tags(iris, "Species")
```